# Eliminar repetições dentro do While

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, array

Tenho uma pesquisa que pega os 3 resultados mais relevantes no meu BD, e então separo as categorias desses 3 resultados em um array dentro de um While, logo fica algo como:

```
while($x = $x->fetch()){
   $array = explode(',', $x["categoria"]));
   foreach($categoria as $array){
      $->busca no banco de dados cada categoria
      $->while convertendo e retornando os dados relacionados
   }
}
```

E dentro do foreach eu quero fazer a pesquisa pelos resultados relacionados a categoria do array em questão, o porém é que quando um resultado se encaixa em mais de uma categoria o mesmo vem duplicado na lista, minhas dúvidas são: Como posso eliminar essas duplicações? Vai ficar pesado 3 laços de repetições um dentro do outro?

Comment: Sim, fica pesado. Eu recomendo fazer toda a consulta, receber todos os dados e daí, pegar o que precisa.

Comment: Posso fazer 3 pesquisas diferentes, pegando 1 resultado relevante por vez, assim diminuo 1 laço de repetição, mas ainda fica o problema das repetições dentro do foreach

Comment: Bom... eu iria editar o teu código... mas, preferi que você olhe como está o teu foreach: *Não está faltando algo?*
--- `foreach ($array as $categoria)`

Comment: sim só percebi depois que postei, mas esse é só um código de exemplo, no original está com o "as"

Comment: Dá uma olhada na função array_map() do PHP, talvez seja possível otimizar um pouco o código, já que ela é mais rápida do que fazer as iterações no PHP.

Outra ideia é colocar as categorias em um Array e fazer a sua busca de dados relacionados utilizando a cláusula IN do banco, ao invés de pesquisar cada uma delas separadamente em cada iteração.

Comment: Newton se eu usar um IN direto no array sem foreach nem nada, o php da erro de "Array to conversion to string"

Answer (score 1):

Olá.
Você pode resolver diretamente na sua consulta do SQL adicionando um GROUP BY pelo código do elemento que você busca.
Muito mais simples e mais rápido.